# Should we have tags for individual articles of clothing?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should we have tags for individual articles of clothing?

Articles of clothing, such as pants, dresses, hats, etc. can be part of many types of crafts. For instance: [sewing](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/1726/how-can-i-add-an-internal-pocket-to-pants-that-dont-have-one), [crocheting](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/1944/how-can-i-resize-this-crocheted-hat-pattern-for-an-infant), [costume design](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/498/what-glues-can-attach-plastic-to-satin) and cosplay.

Do we leave this under the umbrella tag of [clothing](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clothing) for people that work with apparel, or [costume-design](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/costume-design)?

Do we treat them more like material/medium tags?

Do we just create tags for the craft *fields* that deal with specific apparel, such as [shoemaking](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shoemaking), [millinery](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/millinery)/[hatmaking](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hatmaking), [dressmaking](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dressmaking)?

Some other option, or combination of options?

If we have any such tags, when do we use them?

---

This was prompted by the creation of the [hats](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hats) tag, made in levity due to the upcoming Winter Bash, but I think it's worth discussing. I am not a clothing maker, so *I* don't know if there's a real difference in skill need to make pants vs shirts. But, observedly, making hats, footwear and dresses can be much more complicated, and completely separate skills & occupations.

Comment: Would it not be easier to allow the tag for now? In a general sense I would think we could give it a chance. It is not likely to get away from us given the sites size. Like you say it can certainly be a focus when it comes to hats. It is an article that has several unique properties compared to other clothing items. I would be hard pressed to think that it adds 0 value to the post.

Comment: @Matt We currently have many questions about clothes and at least one more about hats. Our decision could mean some retagging.

Comment: So, hats aren't really "clothes"... not in my mind. They'll generally require specialty processes that don't relate to sewing in the way normal clothing does.

Comment: @Catija Same with boots. But are all hats the same in terms of needing special processes? What about the crocheted hat question?

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why a crocheted hat question needs a special tag over any other crocheted project. If we think about it in terms of "specializations", "hats" (if it is to exist) should probably relate more specifically to millinery.

Answer (score 2):

At this point in time, I  would say that we should not.

**What** someone is making isn't as important as the process that they are using.

If they are making a felt vest or a felt hat, it's the "felting" that's important, not whether it's a vest or a hat. Someone is unlikely to specialize in all possible types of hats... crocheted, knitted, felted, etc... but they are going to specialize in that process and that's what we want to tag.